# Haskell - setup config on Windows

Tags: haskell

I have running Haskell as Interpreter either standalone or in Eclipse. Both work quite find and I can also write functional working code. Now I want to test it without the interpreter.

Normally the ghci launches from/in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\winghci\` but I see that the ghc is located in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\bin\`

The reason for a standalone-test is to get an idea about the difference between the ghci and the compiler. If I e.g. call the program like:

```
ghci-7.6.3 myfirtTest.hs
```

then I get as error message:

```
Could not find module `Data.Digits'
Perhaps you meant
  Data.DList (from dlist-0.6.0.1)
  Data.Bits (needs flag -package haskell2010-1.1.1.0)
  Data.DList (needs flag -package dlist-0.5)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I guess it has to do something with the path. I didn't find a specific hint how resp. where to set explicitly. Any hints how to specify the path properly so the Imports will ge resolved properly?

**Edit1**

After some hints from the first comments I executed as well:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin>cabal install dlist 
Resolving dependencies... 
All the requested packages are already installed: 
dlist-0.6.0.1 
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

So, I even more confused since obviously it mentions it is installed, but on the other hand not? I have a simple Haskell-install, no real fancy stuff around it. Therefore I would have expected everything worx out of the box.

Comment: I don't think `Data.Digits` comes default with the haskell platform.  You probably need to download it with cabal.

Comment: uhu, didn't test THAT possibility. And after download where to store resp. how to integrate in Haskell?

Comment: `cabal` will take care of storing and integrating it for you.

Comment: try `cabal install dlist` or similar inside `cmd`

Answer (score 1):

`Data.Digits` is part of the [digits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/digits) package.  You can install it with `cabal install digits`.  When GHC cannot find `Data.Digits`, it suggests modules in packages which you have installed---in this case, `dlist`.